# Time series as stationary stochastic process

Tags: time-series, self-study

(This is a homework problem.)

> Check if the following series is covariance stationary:
>   $$
> \newcommand{\if}{\text{if }}
> Z_t = \begin{cases}
>         X_t     &\if t\text{ is even},   \\
>         X_t + a &\if t\text{  is odd}  \\
>       \end{cases}
> $$
>   where $a$ is constant and $X_t$ is a covariance stationary series (given $E(X_t)=U$).

This is what I tried.  If $X_t$ is covariance stationary then on taking the expectation of both sides I got:
$$
E(Z_t) = \begin{cases}
           U     &\if t \text{ is even},  \\
           U + a &\if t \text{ is odd}  \\
         \end{cases}
$$
And now since $E(Z_t)$ depends on $t \Rightarrow$ it's not covariance stationary (or even stationary in mean). Is my approach right?

Comment: And while you are following gung's suggestions please review the question. I doubt that the statement as it was given by you is correct, i.e. it seems to me that $Z_t$ is not covariance stationary for arbitrary $a$.

Comment: i apologize for previous mistakes,.,., i believe its ok now